# If a system has an internal energy equal to 0, does this mean it doesn't exist?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

Enthalpy is a measure of energy in a thermodynamic system:

> It includes the internal energy, which is the energy required to create > a system, and the amount of energy required to make room for it by
>   displacing its environment and establishing its volume and pressure.

Source: [Wikipedia / Enthalpy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy)

My question is related to internal energy not enthalpy.

Comment: That depends on your precise definition of internal energy and what you mean by "exist", but e.g. an ideal gas at zero temperature would probably have zero internal energy.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "system". One could argue that a mechanical system such as a point mass, or a solid, has zero internal energy as it has no microscopic internal structure. All its energy is in the form of marcroscopic mechanical energy.

Comment: null internal energy is just a reference. In most thermodynamics systems ( try to account of the energy vacuum ) , it is impossible to calculate the total internal energy ( wiki ).

Comment: Complete vaccum has no internal energy. But still, you may consider it as a system which can have coordinates.Doesn't complete vaccum exist!!

Comment: Also, remember that only $\mathrm dU$ is defined: $U$ is always underdetermined (you can shift $U\to U+\text{const}$ for any constant, without changing the physics).